# Uppaal simulation Error : state not well define

Tags: uppaal

I am new to uppaal. I have a system consisting of different models. I also have a clock and a double variable declared.

For my invariants and guards, there is a need for me to check these two values (Clock t; double y; invariant: t<=y or for guard t==y or ty).

Now at the point of the simulation, I have this error

> The successors of this state are not well defined. SymbolicState:clock: Model.t -> double

I have no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: The symbolic simulator does not support floating point operations: either use concrete simulator or replace double with integer.

Comment: Thank you @mariusm. How do I use the concrete simulator in place of the symbolic simulator? I am just learning to find my way around uppaal.  Thank you